# SYMLINK to Directory for all files

Tags: unix

I want to symlink all the files which start with "sun" in the dir /myTest/logs/ to /finalProject/logs/sun

i tried using `ln -sd /finalProject/logs/sun /myTest/logs/*`

but i get error saying target is not a dir.

can somebody help.

Comment: `ln -s /finalProject/logs/sun* /myTest/logs/`

Comment: Then maybe the target directory does not (yet) exist? You have to create it before you can create a link in there.

Comment: it does.i get this error for a few files in this target dir.

Answer (score 0):

You can't symlink multiple files with a single command. But a little bash for loop will do what you need:

```
for i in /finalProject/logs/sun*
do
ln -s $i /myTest/logs/
done
```